# Avalonia, Style not updating upon change

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

Avalonia doing something odd 
using AvaloniaApp template

```
public void ToggleTheme(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Mode: " + App.Fluent.Mode.ToString() + " Styles[0]: " + Application.Current!.Styles[0].ToString());
        if (App.Fluent.Mode == FluentThemeMode.Dark)
        {
            App.Fluent.Mode = FluentThemeMode.Light;
        }
        else if (App.Fluent.Mode == FluentThemeMode.Light)
        {
            App.Fluent.Mode = FluentThemeMode.Dark;
        }
        Application.Current!.Styles[0] = App.Fluent;
        Application.Current.Styles[1] = App.DataGridFluent;
    }
```

got it as a click to my button 
debug output

```
Mode: Dark Styles[0]: Avalonia.Themes.Fluent.FluentTheme
Mode: Light Styles[0]: Avalonia.Themes.Fluent.FluentTheme
Mode: Dark Styles[0]: Avalonia.Themes.Fluent.FluentTheme
Mode: Light Styles[0]: Avalonia.Themes.Fluent.FluentTheme
```

do i have to reload something? 
https://github.dev/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/tree/master/samples/ControlCatalog 
code used, changed it from Combobox to button

btw anyone knows what's up with Avalonia.Default? 
Are Default styles still not Mode implemented?

It seems that the event is not firing on the list, is there outside workaround i could use?

```
Application.Current.Styles.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Updated");
```

Can I modify the list from outside to raise an event on item change?

```
public override void Initialize()
        {
            Styles.Insert(0, Fluent);
            Styles.Insert(1, DataGridFluent);
            AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
        }
```

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/3495
Found this issue but it is said to be fixed